Why I'm having problems with gcs to s3 using glue script
I am having problems when trying to read the data from gcs and I want to write to s3 using aws glue script but it was not working. Can anyone suggest me the proper approach to do the task gcs to s3 using physpark script in glue.
I'm getting issue like:

Error Category: UNCLASSIFIED_ERROR; An error occurred while calling o108.load. No FileSystem for scheme "gs"

